# Initialize a Literal enum in a pydantic model

Tags: python, pydantic

pydantic supports regular enums just fine, and one can initialize an enum-typed field using both an enum *instance* and an enum *value*:

```py
from enum import Enum
from pydantic import BaseModel

class MyEnum(Enum):
    FOO = 'foo'
    BAR = 'bar'

class MyModel(BaseModel):
    x: MyEnum

MyModel(x=MyEnum.BAR)  # Enum instance, works
MyModel(x='foo')       # Enum value, works
MyModel(x='?')         # Fails, as expected
```

pydantic also supports `typing.Literal`:

```py
from typing import Literal
from pydantic import BaseModel

class MyModel(BaseModel):
    x: Literal['foo']

MyModel(x='foo')  # Works
MyModel(x='bar')  # Fails, as expected
```

Now I want to combine enums and literals, i.e. force a field value to equal one particular enum instance. However, I still want to be able to pass the correct enum *value* (i.e. not only the correct enum *instance*), and that doesn't seem to work:

```py
from enum import Enum
from typing import Literal
from pydantic import BaseModel

class MyEnum(Enum):
    FOO = 'foo'
    BAR = 'bar'

class MyModel(BaseModel):
    x: Literal[MyEnum.FOO]

MyModel(x=MyEnum.FOO)  # Enum instance, works
MyModel(x=MyEnum.BAR)  # Fails, as expected
MyModel(x='foo')       # Enum value, fails but I'd like it to work
```

Comment: There is now an open ticket for this (at the time of writing): https://github.com/samuelcolvin/pydantic/issues/2257

Answer (score 19):

Try to use *string based* `Enum`. Like so:

```
from enum import Enum
from typing import Literal
from pydantic import BaseModel


class MyEnum(str, Enum):
    FOO = 'foo'
    BAR = 'bar'


class MyModel(BaseModel):
    x: Literal[MyEnum.FOO]


MyModel(x=MyEnum.FOO)  # Enum instance, works
# MyModel(x=MyEnum.BAR)  # Fails, as expected
MyModel(x='foo')       # String value, works
```

Comment: That's clever, thanks! I'm not sure whether subclassing `str` will work in all use cases, but it should in mine.

Comment: This can be found in the docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#others

Comment: In Python 3.11+ there is even a pre-built class for this: [enum.StrEnum](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#enum.StrEnum)

Answer (score 2):

You might have noticed that an `Enum` based class attribute is not of type `str`. Accessing the actual value of the attribute can be achieved using `.value`.

Please refer to: https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html

Example:

```
>>> from enum import Enum

>>> class MyEnum(Enum):
...    FOO = 'foo'
...    BAR = 'bar'

>>> MyEnum.FOO
<MyEnum.FOO: 'foo'>
>>> type(MyEnum.FOO)
<enum 'MyENum'>
```

You need to retrieve the actual value of it like this:

```
>>> MyEnum.FOO.value
'foo'
>>> type(MyEnum.FOO.value)
str
>>> MyEnum.FOO.name
'FOO'
```